# Complex splitting of a log4net logger between two appenders

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to have 2 log files in my application. The first logs all messages for all loggers, except for the DEBUG output of a specific verbose logger, which I would like to go into the second log file.

I would still like to see INFO - FATAL messages from the verbose logger going into the first log file. Is this possible?

I saw the suggestion of adding a threshold element to the appender-refs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186378/log4net-logging-of-two-different-levels-to-two-different-appenders-for-the-same), but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="fileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log4net" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
  </root>

  <!-- Separate appender for the Verbose logger debug output -->
  <appender name="verboseDebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="verboselog" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
  <logger name="VerboseLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />

    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <appender-ref ref="verboseDebugAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
    </appender-ref>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </appender-ref>
  </logger>

</log4net>
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186378/log4net-logging-of-two-different-levels-to-two-different-appenders-for-the-same/21188397#21188397

Comment: That's the question I linked to above. I tried it but adding the threshold element to the appender-ref didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

one problem i see:

remove these lines

```
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<appender-ref ref="verboseDebugAppender">
  <threshold value="ALL" />
</appender-ref>
<appender-ref ref="fileAppender">
  <threshold value="ERROR" />
</appender-ref>
```

and change

```
 <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
  </root>
```

to

```
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="verboseDebugAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
    </appender-ref>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </appender-ref>
</root>
```