# Log4net - modify logging levels for individual logger and appender combinations

Tags: log4net

I have two appenders, one (InfoAppender) with a levelMin info filter and one (DebugAppender) without filter. This works great. I can also set minimum logging levels for individual loggers using the  element. But now I want to have most loggers logging info (and above) to InfoAppender and debug (and above) to DebugAppender, but a certain chatty logger (NHibernate) logging warn (and above) to InfoAppender and info (and above) to DebugAppender.

I looked at the solution provided in [Log4Net Logging of two different levels to two different appenders for the same logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186378/log4net-logging-of-two-different-levels-to-two-different-appenders-for-the-same), but it doesn't work for me. I have the following configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="InfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Logs\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="'Info.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log.txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Logs\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="'Debug.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log.txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender">
      <threshold value="WARN" />
    </appender-ref>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender">
      <threshold value="INFO" />
    </appender-ref>
  </logger>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I have the following test code:

```
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        var logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger("Program");
        var logger2 = LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate");
        logger1.Debug("Debug message");
        logger2.Debug("Debug message");
        logger1.Info("Info message");
        logger2.Info("Info message");
        logger1.Warn("Warn message");
        logger2.Warn("Warn message");
```

But both debug messages are logged to DebugAppender and both info messages are logged to InfoAppender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration mechanism of log4net is quite lenient but doesn't tell you when some parameters are not taken into account. For example in your configuration the following references the appender `InfoAppender` but the threshold property doesn't do anything

```
 <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender">
    <threshold value="WARN" />
  </appender-ref>
```

No parsing of xml element below the `appender-ref` node occur, you could put anything it won't be taken into account:

```
protected void ParseChildrenOfLoggerElement(XmlElement catElement, Logger log, bool isRoot)
// some code ommited
        if (xmlElement.LocalName == "appender-ref")
        {
            IAppender appender = this.FindAppenderByReference(xmlElement);
            string attribute = xmlElement.GetAttribute("ref");
            if (appender != null)
            {
                LogLog.Debug(string.Concat(new string[]
                {
                    "XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Adding appender named [",
                    attribute,
                    "] to logger [",
                    log.Name,
                    "]."
                }));
                log.AddAppender(appender);
            }
            else
            {
                LogLog.Error("XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Appender named [" + attribute + "] not found.");
            }
        }
```

What you need to do is add a filter between your logger and your final appender. To do this I recommend using the [`ForwardingAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ForwardingAppenderMembers.html) which lets you pass log events between appenders while adding some behavior: change the NHibernate section of your config file to this:

```
<appender name="NHibernateDebugFilterAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ForwardingAppender">
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
  </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="NHibernateInfoFilterAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ForwardingAppender">
  <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="WARN" />
  </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateInfoFilterAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateDebugFilterAppender"/>
</logger>
```